# Do I neet Unity of Work and Repository patterns when working with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So at my job I was pointed to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990492/RESTful-Day-sharp-Enterprise-Level-Application#_Toc418969121 and was told to learn these patterns and implement them in my solution.

What confused me was that these things were before entity framework 6 and from what I understood, Unity of Work is used to optimize database performance by grouping queries together. Since EF6 has already these optimizations, should I still implement these layers? I get that the layerness helps with modularization and switching of data source. Does that mean that EF6 is too complex to implement with these patterns and should ADO.Net be used directly or something like that?

EDIT: I've noticed that this added layer allows usage of mock data sources. Not sure how useful this is because of the need to add another layer of apstraction

[image]

Comment: of course not, A `Console` application is enough if you just want to start with `EF`.

Answer (score 2):

"Unit of Work is used to optimize database performance by grouping queries together." - This is not correct. Unit of Work is there to collect related operations together into a single transaction which is then committed or rolled back as a whole. It tracks changes made to objects so that required database operations can be deduced automatically and performed on your behalf.

When you work with Entity Framework, you use it to create DbContext from model. That class is both the Repository and Unit of Work, so you don't have to do anything special. Things only become more complicated than that when your project becomes so large that DbContext becomes more of a burden.

Comment: So does that mean these patterns are not needed when layering my application?

Comment: That means that you don't have to do anything, just use DbContext classes generated by Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

`Repository` is used to abstract your application from datasource, but since `EntityFramework` implements this pattern by itself and gives you a possibility to change data source seamlessly, there is no neccesity to add one more layer of abstraction.

You will just limit `EF` possibilities, while creating something like `GenericRepository<T>`. And nevertheless you won't be able to replace `EF` by another library with no changes to your code, even if you implement such a layer. (Some queries written for `EF` will fail for `NHibernate`, for example).

Just don't use `DbContext` everywhere in your application (inside UI code at least), use it by your data access layer (services with business dependent methods or something in that way).

Even for scenarios, where some cloud data storage is used (which `EF` won't be able to handle seamlessly), there is no neccessity for that layer, it's better to introduce separate classes and use them explicitly, because you cannot fit db and cloud interaction into one abstraction, it will start leaking at some point.

Comment: So UoW and repo are pattern used for abstracting data layer and are not a part of the busines logic layer?

Comment: They used to implement interaction between your business logic layer and data source. So business logic has knowledge about repo, while repo knows about data source. While business logic layer is the highest one, it performs some actions with use of repo and then commits or rolls them back.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is a UnitOfWork/Repository pattern itself. If you need to abstract yourself from EF, then you could implement a layer on top of EF with your own UoW/Rep pattern.

This is good if you want to replace EF at some point in your proyect.

The cons? I think that building a UoW on top of EF gives you a redundant architecture and you will end up writing more code for something that maybe will never change.

In my current proyect, the main structure is very common, with a Data layer (with a sublayer for the Entities) for EF, Logic layer (where I put all the Business Logic) and the View layer (It can be web, or whatever). With that structure I directly invoke EF in the Logic layer.